# Database: `One to One` vs `One to Many`

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-many, one-to-one

**Note: This is not an inventory controlling system. I am just trying to map which medication given to which patient. I am not considering how many medication packets etc. Just a single medication event**

I am having a sudden confusion with database relationships, even after working with them for years. Below is my situation.

I have a table called `patient` where it will hold the information of patients. I have another table called `medication` where it will hold the medicines prescribed for `patient`s. 
I want to find the relationship, so I asked the below questions from me.

1. Can one patient have many medicine prescribed? - Answer: YES
2. Can one prescribed medicine have many patients? - Answer: No (ex: you can't give a patient a paracetamol to drink, take it out and give it to someone else)

**I need to create the foreign key of `patient` in `medication` table.** I'm confused, because my answer for 1st question tell me it is `one to many` relationship while the answer for 2nd says me it is `one to one` relationship.

What is the exact relation when I am planning to add the foreign key of `patient` in `medication` table?

Below is my structure

[image]

Comment: you are confusing yourself by assuming one tablet is distinnguishable from another.

Comment: @e4c5: Sure, agree. What do you think, any explanation?

Comment: Hi, if you do not have medicines stored as packages, then I believe you'll need a many to many relation. For example Aspirin can be prescribed to more than one patient and a patient can have more than one prescribed medicines. If you have the detail on package level then it sounds like a one-to-many relation, one patient can have more than one prescribed medicines, but a package of medicine can be prescribed to only one patient.

Comment: It would help to better define things. What you call `medication` is in fact `medication_event`, so you distinguish between **paracetamol** as a medicine and **parametamol given to John Doe on 12/19/2016 14:55**. Once you have this as an **event** I don't quite see the need to create foreign keys.

Comment: @FDavidov: Your example is correct. But we still have to track which medicine is given to `john doe` that is why I created this medication table.

Comment: No really. If your table for `mediation_event` includes a reference to the `patients` table, there would not be a need for foreign key. See? You are taking medicines from table `medications`, administer them to a patient from table `patients`, and recording the administration event of the medicine in table `medication_events`.

Comment: This is a really good question with the context that is being laid out! +1

Comment: _what does your database structure look like currently_

Comment: @Jhecht: Structure uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It somewhat depends on the kind of structure of your tables.

**Example 1**

```
Patient:

PatientID Name
--------- ----
1         John
2         Matt

Patient_Medication:

PrescriptionID PatientID Name
-------------- --------- ------------
1              1         Antacid
2              1         Paracetamol
3              2         Asthma inhaler
```

You are in a one to many relationship. Patient `John` can have multiple medications in prescription table.

**Example 2**

```
Patient:

PatientID Name
--------- ----
1         John
2         Matt
3         Katie

Medication:

MedicationID Name
------------ ----
1            Antacid
2            Paracetamol
3            Asthma inhaler

Patient_Medication:

ID  PatientID MedicationID
--- --------- ------------
1   1 (John)        1 (Antacid)
2   1 (John)        2 (Paracetamol)
3   2 (Matt)        3 (Asthma inhaler)
4   3 (Katie)       2 (Paracetamol)
5   3 (Katie)       3 (Asthma inhaler)
```

This situation is a many-to-many relationship where many patients can have many medications and vice versa. Usually Patient_Medication is called a junction table.

Comment: Your 1st example is what I have. So to confirm, the foreign key is in `medication` table and it is a `one to many`, isn't it. OK so how do we "think"  this? This is the answer when I asked "Can one patient have many medicine prescribed?" question from me. There I was thinking about user who is going to use the medicine. Is this is how we "think" ?

Comment: Yes, foreign key is in medication table and it is one to many. We think about data in this way - Your front-end application is used by a doctor, let's assume. Doctor sees `John` and enters his info into your app. `John` becomes a patient in your table. Doctor prescribes 3 medications. 3 rows (one for each medicine) gets entered in `medication` for that patient. That makes one to many relationship in the first table.

Comment: Yes. "One" side is at the 'patient ' table and "many" side is at the 'medication' table. The foreign key will be placed on 'medication' table, isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the relationship should actually be many-to-many.  A given patient record could point to several different medications, and similarly a given medication record could point to several different patients.

One way to implement this would be to create a third table which maps patients to medications (or medications to patients, if you prefer to think of it that way).  This table might look like this:

```
id | patient_id | medication_id | date
1  | 1          | 1             | 2016-12-19
2  | 1          | 2             | 2016-12-18
3  | 2          | 2             | 2016-12-18
```

The above data would imply that patient 1 took medications 1 and 2, and medication 2 was also being taken by patient 2.  I also added a date, which might be a proxy for a given patient visit.

The `medication_id` could be a unique identifier for a given pack of medication delievered.  In another table, each unique medication would be related to a parent table for that medication.

**Update:**

Your current schema does not look far off, except that the table you labelled `medication` is actually a bridge table between patients and their medication dosages.  You would need a third table which stores the metadata for each medication.  This metadata would be constant for *all* medication dosages, e.g. type of drug, cost, etc.

Comment: `a given medication record could point to several different patients` - No, this is incorrect. One record is 100% only for one patient. Maybe 100 patients are there with the same fever, but their record should be unique and not mixed.

Comment: @PeakGen I think you are confusing the reality of patient records with database design.  From a database design point of view, a medication doesn't "know" that it actually belongs to anyone.  Rather, the same medication can be associated with any patient.

Comment: Right, you are refering to medication "packs". No, I am talking about 'medication event'. Ex: 25mg paracetamol to John Doe. We save the medication name, gram etc separatly.

Comment: @PeakGen It is still a many-to-many relationship.  Each medication "event" represents an interaction between several patients and several medications.  Hence, I could grab a given patient, and a date, or range of dates, and generate a basket of medications.  Or, I could grab a medication, and a range of dates, and generate a basket of patients.

Comment: Hello @PeakGen, Tim is right. There is a many-to-many relationship. I guess you are getting confused between table holding the just medication names and actual medication quantity. Solution to you problem might be to think "What if doctor has to give same medication to two patients". By your way, it would not be possible. (e.g. Paracetomol 25mg to two patients).

Comment: Yes I do get you. For your comment to work, there should be a controlling of "medication packs" like in an inventory controlling system, so I can link to that table and point the id. But there is no such table here.

Comment: I have also uploaded the structure.

Comment: Had a look at your update. This is not an application like that, patient insert the information. He is not going to insert drug cost etc and we are not going to provide them too. When such is not required there is no use of creating such table at all. he is just going to insert the "medication name" he took in the morning and so on. This is a connection between the patient and that single tablet he took, we don't have to know the cost of it, how many packs of it, how many remains, because there is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question:

2. **Can one prescribed medicine have many patients? - Answer: No (ex: you can't give a patient a paracetamol to drink, take it out and give it to someone else)**

I guess here you have assumed that prescribing a medication and actually consuming that mediation (actual tablet) in real world is the same thing.

The medication table is just a name holder for the medication.

Your answer would have been correct if your table "Medication" would be storing actual instances of medication.

E.g.

Medication

Id    Name

1     Paracetomol 25mg Instance 1

2     Paracetomol 25mg Instance 2

3     Paracetomol 25mg Instance 3

Now here, table is actually containing medication instances which can not be consumed by two patients. And here your answer "No" is, I guess, correct.

The other thing is, as you said you are not working on inventory system, and just trying to map medication, you are still attached to real world inventory item which cannot be consumed by two patients.

Here you are mixing inventory item in a system where inventory item is not required.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So `one to many` isnt it. This is the answer I got when I asked my self "Can one patient have many medicine prescribed?" question from me. There I was thinking about user who is going to use the medicine. Is this is how we "think" ?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion I made. Maybe bad english. I don't know if my answer makes it clear what I was trying to say.. but I will say, it is a Many to many relationship. Maybe you can go through the answer again or I will try to put it more easily understandable.

Comment: Your given example is correct, storing real medcine instances. Just forget packet and medicine packs, there is no stock, there is nothing like that and there will never be

Comment: Storing real medicine instances is like maintaining stock, Don't you agree? If you dont want to deal stock (inventory), there will be no instances in the table, just the name of medication in the table, in this case Just Paracetomol 25mg.

Comment: Yes. That is what we do,  no stock. So, one to many relationship and the foreign key will be on `medication` isnt it

Comment: If there is a one to many relationship and the foriegn key is on medication, how you plan to prescribe any medication (e.g.Paracetomol ) to two patients A and B? Is the medication table will hold two entries for Paracetomol?

Comment: yes. There is no use of 2 tables in this application.

Answer (score 0):

Could your confusion be the result of not having defined what the medication table actually represents. It seems to me that your are confusing type of medicine and actual packets.

So what kind of relationship are you trying to model? Are you doing a system that can do inventory of how much medicine you have, or are you doing a patient system that can tell you how many patients are getting a particular medication.

I think your answer to question two is wrong, many patients can be on the same medication. The number of packets you have in stock should be handled in a separate table where you could hold information on things like how many packets you have, what their location is and so on.

So you need at least three tables

patient - holds the patient
medication - holds the types of medication
patient_medication - holds the information on what types of medication the patient is on

you can then add things like another table to hold information on how much of a medication you have and where it's stored if that is relevant to the system.

Comment: Nope, I am not talking about packs. I am talking about exact medication prescribed to one patient. Ex: Paracetomol 25mg to John Doe

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong to say that the association is one-to-many in one direction, and one-to-one in the other direction. When planning a database, I often advise people to write out the associations in both directions:

- Each patient can have zero or more medications
- Each medication belongs to one and only one patient

This helps to determine the cardinality of the relationship and clarify functional dependencies. When only one direction is specified, it can be difficult to distinguish one-to-many from many-to-many associations.

When talking about the relationship as a whole, we take an "overhead perspective" and ignore the perspective of individual entities, so we would call this example one-to-zero-or-more, or commonly just one-to-many.

Many-to-many relationships look like two one-to-many associations when you view it from the perspective of individual entities on either side.

Comment: To make it a many-to-many I need to have the list of medications as a separate table. @zedfoxus 2nd example is a scenario. I do not have this list of medications, I don't even know what they are. Patient will be the one entering whether he had medication or not. he will insert them as "Panadol 25mg" and thats all.