# DbContext returns some null fields

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

**Q:** When I try to return data from `_Db` I get null object in `List` properties and I wonder why others properties are being returned correctly, while `List` isn't?

**Explanation of a problem**: I have `ApplicationDbContext` class that has 
`public IDbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }` property. With the following `ApplicationDbInitializer` class:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Players.Add(new Player { PlayerName = "john", PlayerSkills = new List<string> { "a", "b" } });
        context.Players.Add(new Player { PlayerName = "Wuli", PlayerSkills = new List<string> { "c", "d" } });

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

My `Player` class looks like this:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public List<string> PlayerSkills { get; set; }
 }
```

My request to data looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Player> Get()
{
    return _Db.Players;
}
```

It returns `Id` and `PlayerName` absolutely correctly, but `null` for `PlayerSkills` List.

`_Db` is being initialized in the same `Controller` class as `Get()` in the following way:

```
ApplicationDbContext _Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Comment: From SQL point of view, what type of field should `PlayerSkills` have to store collection of strings?

Comment: well, just kicking the bush.. is it code first, model first, database first? if it's database first [Sergey Berenzovskiy answer will do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42026587/4648586) - perhaps. also, a bit point that may affect things.. is it entity core? or the entity framework 6? ah! looking at your `public List<string> PlayerSkills` i wonder if you understood a [one to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217027/database-one-to-one-vs-one-to-many)..

Comment: @BagusTesa it's code first and entity framework 6. Yeah, it's possible that I've missed some concepts - 1st time working with db.

Answer (score 3):

There is type of field in SQL which can store collection of values. If you'll take a look on table which was generated by EF, you will not see `PlayerSkills` filed there. And creation script will look like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [PlayerName] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Players] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

That's why you don't get any data in `PlayerSkills` field. If you want to store *one to many* relations in SQL database, you need second table which will store player skills and id of player which those skills are related to. Or even two tables if you want to avoid duplication of skills - one for skills, and junction table for mapping players to skills.

---

Without junction table (if you don't want explicit property for foreign key, then your option is fluent mapping instead of attribute mapping):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasMany(p => p.PlayerSkills).WithRequired();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

PlayerSkills

```
public class PlayerSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Player

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PlayerSkill> PlayerSkills { get; set; }
}
```

---

With junction table

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasMany(p => p.PlayerSkills)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(j => j.MapLeftKey("PlayerId")
                   .MapRightKey("PlayerSkillId")
                   .ToTable("PlayerToSkill"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to access a property from a Database that is an ICollection, You need to include it like below:

```
public IEnumerable<Player> Get()
{
    return _Db.Players.Include(p => p.PlayerSkills );
}
```

this way, the PlayerSkills field is not null anymore.